# Ubuntu 14.04 - brightness problem in HP hybrid laptop

Tags: graphics, brightness

In a HP sleekbook 15 laptop I managed to install NVidia driver and also quick switch graphics is working. When NVidia card is active I can adjust the brightness using keyboard but when intel card is active the adjust is not possible. I have to mention that I have followed next advice
 "Edit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf as root. Enter the following text:

```
          Section "Device"
          Identifier "card0"
          Driver "intel"
          Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
          BusID "PCI:0:2:0"

          EndSection                "
```

but still doesnt work for intel graphic card.

Someone can help? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! The solution of user "Gtx" worked for my LG P530-K.AE23B. Changing brightness was impossible since 13.04 version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

or `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the value so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

then apply grub configs: `sudo update-grub`

and **reboot**

This worked for my HP ProBook.

Solution found here: http://www.techjail.net/solved-brightness-problem-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin.html

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion but did not work for me. After "sudo update-grub" I restarted and after this I was not able to switch between graphic cards and also NVidia Prime profile it is lost. When I made the change back then I have the initial situation, that means I am able to switch between cards and adjusting of brightness by keyboard it is possible only for NVidia card. For Intel card it is possible only from System settings--> Brightness&Lock.

Comment: ooops! Sorry... Seems that it is working only after rebooting the system two times. A little strange: I followed again your advice, than I rebooted (after first reboot I lost the Prime Profile and was not possible to switch between cards) and then reboot again without doing anything else. After second reboot the prime profile was available, was possible to switch between cards and also possible to adjust brightness by keyboard for both cards. Then Iagain rebooted few times and seems that it is ok... Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me. I have HP ProBook 4430s. Thanks :)

Comment: It didn't work for my Dell Inspiron 15r

Comment: Works perfectly for HP ProBook 4440. Thank you.