# Can't adjust screen brightness ((

Tags: keyboard, brightness

Can't adjust screen brightness from anywhere. Nor by specific buttons on the laptop keyboard, nor by setting in "brightness and lock"

I've tried to configure the grub file like it mentioned in a lot of instruction, but noe success.

When I'm pressing the brigtness buttons on a keyboard I get a bar appeard on screen but there's only two positions and no any actual brightness changes (((

Unfrtunately couldn't attache images due to lack of reputation (

Do somebody knows how to fix it ?

Thanks in avdvance.

Comment: Please list the make and model of your computer. Different makes models have different solutions sometimes.

Comment: Please also include the output of `uname -a`  I had this same problem during kernel 3.13.0-32

Comment: sorry for a stupid question guys... but how to "list the make and model of your computer." ?? )... I'm a quite new in all of that stuff. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+T, which will open command line. Then you can type `uname -a` and hit enter. Copy and paste here whatever that command tells you. Among other things would be nice to know what `sudo lshw -c display` says

Comment: @AndrewSakharoff While you look for solution, perhaps my script [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/589574/295286) may be helpful, specifically #2 script. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have the Same Problem.This is the way what Works for me.use this [link](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)