# Brightness doesn't work on acer aspire 4741

Tags: drivers, vga

Please, can anybody help me ?
Brightness doesn't work on Acer Aspire 4741.
I use Ubuntu 14.10 x64. The screen is too bright and very painful for my eyes.
Are there any suggestions for me to get a solution?

Comment: Which graphic card? Which driver for graphic card? Which version of driver for graphic card?

Comment: intel graphic 3000

Comment: Xrandr can be used as a work around. I've posted a script that uses it. Hope you may find it useful.  Here: http://askubuntu.com/a/589574/295286

Answer (score 3):

Yes @ Karl is right Brightness option is directly associated with What type of Graphic Card  you have & after New Installation Process, by default keeps this "off" (that is low high can't be done. 
If you have Intel Graphics then:
(To check the graphic card)

type this in Terminal:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

If its Intel, the answer would be:

```
computer_mfg_name intel_backlight
```

Then try this:

Open Terminal & type this to create a config file:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Now we need to edit this file. You can use any editor be it a terminal one or graphical.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the following lines to this file:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Save it. Restart the Computer. The brightness control should be working through function keys now.

Comment: @Ands, please if any of this helped you in the any way either accept this as answer or post update about the problem. Or even down-vote, but do not keep this unanswered. Thanks!

Comment: I had the similar issue on my *Acer Aspire ES-521* in Ubuntu 14.04. I could not adjust brightness via Fn + ← / → hotkeys. I've just installed **fglrx** package. After that hotkeys started functioning properly. 

Of course, installation of additional packages can lead to even more issues. But it's pretty easy to login without GUI and remove those packages (as long as you remember names of the packages or have log/notes about the latest manipulations with `apt-get`).