# Brightness not working Ubuntu 15.04 on acer aspire 7715z

Tags: display

If anyone has any suggestions or links, I'd be truly grateful.  The brightness is not working, the screen stays at maximum brightness.

Thank you for your help.  I followed the instructions from the link below and now the brightness adjustment works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information like: Is it too dark? Is it too bright?  What's the output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/` Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: This works when typed exactly as directed:  

http://askubuntu.com/questions/604869/brightness-doesnt-work-on-acer-aspire-4741


http://askubuntu.com/questions/604869/brightness-doesnt-work-on-acer-aspire-4741

Answer (score 0):

See https://askubuntu.com/a/604913/50254

Basically, do following:

```
 sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add following lines

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Save (`CTRL+X`) and reboot the system. Function keys plus arrows should now correctly adjust the backlight and you have 20 possible levels instead of only 4 levels supported by BIOS.