# How to switch graphics (Intel + AMD? Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, gpu-driver

My video driver working isn't the appropriate. Ubuntu 19.04 is using i915 driver when the correct option is AMD GPU.

```
$sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       descrição: VGA compatible controller
       produto: HD Graphics 620
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 2
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:02.0
       versão: 02
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuração: driver=i915 latency=0
       recursos: irq:129 memória:d1000000-d1ffffff memória:b0000000-bfffffff porta de E/S:f000(tamanho=64) memória:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       descrição: Display controller
       produto: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:01:00.0
       versão: c3
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuração: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       recursos: irq:130 memória:c0000000-cfffffff memória:d0000000-d01fffff porta de E/S:e000(tamanho=256) memória:d0200000-d023ffff memória:d0240000-d025ffff
```

---

```
$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

How do I  change it?

Comment: Wrong. Your system has Intel + AMD graphics therefore the both drivers are needed and both are usually installed by default. What you need to learn is how to switch graphics.

Comment: This will help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068343/switch-between-intel-amd-gpu-on-18-04