# Which VGA is in use if I'm gaming? (amd hybrid laptop)

Tags: 19.10, radeon, intel, hybrid-graphics

I have laptop with hybrid graphic intel and amd. Actually I use Ubuntu 19.10 but from the point of the question its irrelevant. 
The question is:
**How can I decide if my laptop use the dedicated card or the integrated intel when I play a game?** As long as I don't have any control panel to choose the graphic card I dont understand how can I be sure about it.

Before answer please keep in mind this card is not amdgpu ready that's why it uses radeon driver.
Thank you very much in advance for proper answers!

**Information**:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Grap
hics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8850M / R9 M265X] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8850M / R9 M265X]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at c0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
        Expansion ROM at c0540000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
        Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express <?>
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

**Info2**:

```
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:A16]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8850M / R9 M265X] [1002:6823]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] [1002]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:c0500000-c053ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0540000-c055ffff
```

Comment: Suggested title: How can I switch between GPUs on an Intel/AMD hybrid laptop?

Answer (score 0):

On modern systems with Intel/AMD hybrid it's usually Intel by default and if you want to run something on AMD GPU you set environment variable `DRI_PRIME=1` for that process. For example, if you know how to start the process in question from command line you can just add the variable before the command:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep Device
Device: AMD ...
```

As opposed to

```
$ glxinfo | grep Device
Device: Mesa DRI Intel...
```

If you are trying to run Steam game, try this exact line in Launch Options setting for the game:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 %command%
```